# add dynamic products filter page in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, e-commerce

my Filter list is in header component (like men, women, kids etc)
`

```
        <span className="category" onClick={()=>{filter('men')}}>Men </span>
        <span className="category" onClick={()=>{filter('women')}>Women </span>
        <span className="category" onClick={()=>{filter('electronics')}>Electronics </span>
        <span className="category" onClick={()=>{filter('beauty')}>Beauty / Health </span>
        <span className="category" onClick={()=>{filter('accessories')}>Accessories </span>
```

`
what should i write in filter function such that it opens only that category products in different page

the products should be fetched from API

When i click on specific category it should show only that category products,

Comment: you can give a value to span tag , <span value = 'men'  > </span> , and onClick , you can pass event as an parameter , onClick = {(e) => filter(e.target.value)}.. here the value will be 'men'

Answer (score 0):

you can use it :

```
<span className="category" name ="woman" onClick={(event)=>{filter(event.target.name)}>Women </span>
```